# Using Custom Subclass of NS Object in 2 different IBActions

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, nsobject

This is an objective-c problem. I have created a subclass person of NSObject with parameters 'height' and 'weight', with property and synthesize in a file called Person.h that contains both interface and implementation.

I want to import Person.h into my viewcontroller.m and create person objects and alter them using 2 IBActions.

```
-(IBAction)alterperson_1{

 person *bob = [person alloc]init];
 bob.height = 72;
 bob.weight = 200;
}

-(IBAction)alterperson_2{

 bob.height = 80;
 bob.weight = 250;

}
```

This arrangement does not work because the method alterperson_2 can't find Bob because it is a local variable to alterperson_1. My question is how and where in viewcontroller.m do I allocate Bob as a person so that his attributes can be altered by both IBActions.

I have tried allocing in viewdidload as well as in the initwith nibname methods. It did not work. I have also tried in the implementation{ } of viewcontroller.m but that doesn't work either because Bob's allocation is not a compile time constant.

Thanks!

**Update With Code**

So, I have the Person.h file importing properly now (thanks Robotnik), and am able to create instances of Person throughout ViewController.m -- however, my created instance *bob does not seem to retain values for its properties (see comments by NSLog statements in the code). I think this is an initialization issue, but I have no idea where to initialize. Currently, I get a warning when initializing in viewDidLoad. How do I get bob.weight to print 200 when my IBAction is called, instead of the 0 I currently get? Thanks.

```
// Person.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Person : NSObject{

int weight;
int height;
}

@property int weight, height;

@end
```

***end Person.h***

```
//Person.m


#import "Person.h"

@implementation Person

@synthesize weight, height;

@end
```

***end Person.m***

```
//ViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "person.h"



@interface ViewController : UIViewController{


}

@property Person *bob;

-(IBAction)persontest:(id)sender;

@end
```

***end ViewController.h***

```
//ViewController.m

#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize bob;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    Person *bob = [[Person alloc]init]; // this causes a local declaration warning, if I remove this code, however, it still doesn't work
    bob.weight = 100;
    NSLog(@"viewDidLoad bob's weight, %i", bob.weight); // this will print 100, but only because I made the local initialization. The value is lost once the viewDidLoad Method ends.
}

-(IBAction)persontest:(id)sender{

    bob.weight = bob.weight + 100;
    NSLog(@"IBAction bob's weight %i", bob.weight); // this prints 0, probably because value is nil. How can I make it print 200?
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

@end
```

***end ViewController.m***

Comment: Not related to the question, but don't forget that class names should be capitalised, to distinguish them from object names. Also, you're missing a [ from the person alloc line (I'm guessing this is just a typo in the question, not in your actual code).

Comment: You are correct, that is a typo. And I assume capitalization of class names is convention, so, I will update my program to follow it. Thanks Adam!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to declare Bob in your `ViewController.h` if you want him to be accessible across multiple methods. You can then initialise him in viewDidLoad

```
@interface ViewController
{
    Person *bob;
}

-(IBAction)alterperson_1;
-(IBAction)alterperson_2;
@end
```

You mentioned you wanted to instantiate multiple people. In that case you may want to keep multiple Person objects in an `NSMutableArray` or similar. This should still be declared in the `ViewController.h` in order to be accessible in multiple methods. You can then use the method `addObject:` to add people to the array. Here is an example of an array, storing strings.

```
NSMutableArray *stringArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[stringArray addObject:@"Dog"];
[stringArray addObject:@"Cat"];
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I have tried several times to allocate person *bob in viewDidLoad, but then *bob is still not available in my IBActions. I am using ARC, could this be the problem? My objects are being released too soon?

Comment: But did you declare him in the .h file like Robotnik suggested?  This approach (of declaring *bob) will only work if you know all the names of the Person objects you are going to use, since you have to declare a property or ivar for each of them.  Adding them to a collection will retain them (if the array or set is retained), so that's probably the way you want to go.

Comment: Ok, so, I am going to really noob it up here. If I import person.h into viewcontroller.h, then I get a linker command failed error on build. I assume this is because person.h is imported to viewcontroller.h then imported again to viewcontroller.m, which creates multiple copies of person.h. This is why I was only trying to deal with the .m file.

Comment: but if Person.h is in ViewController.h, you don't need it in ViewController.m- because when ViewController.m includes ViewController.h it will also see Person.h

Comment: I'm using XCode 4.3 with ARC. I import Person.h into the ViewController.h only-- I think my problem is that I need to separate Person.h into Person.h and Person.m. I will do this tonight and try when I get home from work. Thanks for you help Robotnik, hopefully this will work.

Comment: Ok, declaring a Person *bob in the ViewController.h does indeed allow me to initialize bob in ViewDidLoad and alter bob in any IBActions. However, I have a new problem now.

Comment: Ok, declaring a Person *bob in the ViewController.h does indeed allow me to initialize bob in ViewDidLoad and call bob in any IBActions. However, I have a new problem now. I code bob.weight = 200 in an IBAction, and I code NSLog(a"this is weight, %i", bob.weight) in that same IBAction. Now, I run simulator and click the associated button, I will get in the output 'this is weight, 0" and not 200. Basically, it seems the variable initialization is not surviving the ViewDidLoad. Is this ARC?

Comment: I'm not sure sorry, can you edit your question with the updated code? (or ask a new question)

Comment: Per jrturton below, the final piece below was me removing '*' when initializing bob in viewDidLoad, so, your initial solution does work. Thanks for your time, Robotnik.

Comment: No worries, glad we could help :)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confusing declaration of a variable with allocation of a variable. You're also not using properties properly.

Declaration of a variable is done like this:

```
Person *bob;
```

That's it. If you put this line in your @interface section, or in {braces} at the top of your implementation section, then this becomes an *instance variable*, any time you use `bob` in the rest of your class it will know that you are talking to a person. So, in your viewDidLoad, you can now do this:

```
bob = [[Person alloc] init];
```

And it knows you are referring to the instance variable. In your current code, you have `Person *` in front of this line, which, as the compiler is telling you, is declaring a *local* variable with the name bob, and therefore hiding your instance variable, so you are not changing your instance variable at all, so there is no value in it later.

Looking at the nature of this question, and your comments, I would strongly advise reading some objective-c introductory texts before proceeding much further. You can ask questions here but SO is not really the place to learn a language - most answerers will assume that you know the language basics.

Comment: I've been stuck on this for 2 days. Although I have a background in C++, SQL, SAS, Visual Basic, Objective C is completely new to me. I've done all The New Boston tutorials on Objective C, which were really helpful, but yea, I've been making quite a few beginner mistakes. This particular problem was driving me nuts, which is why I asked SO. Thanks for your help, and I will devote quite a bit more time this weekend to tutorials.